# Short arithmetic progressions in quadratic residues

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let p be a prime number of form 4k+1.
I guess that there are c(d) number of 3-terms arithmetic progressions (AP) in the set of quadratic residues modulo p, where c(d) is an integer constant depending on the d difference of the progression, i.e. the number of occurrences is independent of p.

In particular when the difference is d = 4, there are c = 8 sets of three-terms AP when p > 17.

Can anybody give a hint how can I prove this?

Comment: It is confusing that $k$ denotes two different things in your question, namely $p=4k+1$ and $k$ is the difference of your AP. It is also confusing that you do not use TeX here.

Answer (score 5):

The statement is false. For example, for the case of $d=1$, it is known that the largest number of consecutive quadratic residues modulo $p$ tends to infinity as $p\to\infty$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716182/consecutive-quadratic-residues) and, for more general patterns, see Seva's answer to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161271/consecutive-non-quadratic-residues). Further related MO entries are [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146258/quadratic-residues-and-nonresidues-of-arbitrary-patterns) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85842/three-consecutive-quadratic-residues-problem).

**Added.** Seva's answer (linked above) shows that the statement is false for every $d$.

Comment: Fair enough.  (I wrote: I guess)  Can you say anything about d = 4 ?

Comment: @Methus: See my added section.